# Calling ExplicitWait method into functional feature

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, selenium-webdriver

I have a `utils` class which has ExplictWait defined and wanted to call and apply that member to a functional feature class extending to the above said `utils` class.

Utils class ExplicitWait Method :

```
public void explicitWait(){

        WebDriverWait waitExplicit = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

    }
```

Functional feature class Method :

```
 public void userLogout(){
    SatusPageElements forLogOut = new SatusPageElements();
        if(driver != null) {
            driver.findElement(forLogOut.profileName).click();

           driver.findElement(forLogOut.logoutLink).click();
        } else{

            System.out.println("No Driver");
```

SatusPageElements is a class where Status page objects defined and profileName and logoutLink are clickable defined in SatusPageElements. In this context, when profileName link is clicked, the logoutLink is displayed to click. There is a little wait time for the Logout link to display. So, I have to apply the wait time for it but team only decided to apply the defined Explicit Wait method.

Any thoughts, please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add explicit wait in your code like this:

Utils class ExplicitWait Method :

```
public WebDriverWait explicitWait(){ // this method returns WebDriverWait instance

    return new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);

}
```

Functional feature class Method :

```
public void userLogout(){ // and then you can use explicitWait() in this method
    SatusPageElements forLogOut = new SatusPageElements();
        if(driver != null) {
            UtilsClass uc = new UtilsClass(); // create instance of class where explicitWait()
            uc.explicitWait().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(forLogOut.profileName))
            driver.findElement(forLogOut.profileName).click();
            uc.explicitWait().until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(forLogOut.logoutLink))
            driver.findElement(forLogOut.logoutLink).click();
        } else{

        System.out.println("No Driver");
```

The sample construction of WebDriverWait looks like this:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

PS: it is always good to use explicit wait instead of implicit wait, because explicit waits are more flexible since you don't have to wait the whole ammout of time if the element already ready to interact with it.

Comment: I tried it and it throws the following error :
"Cannot resolve method 'until'(org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions<org.openqa.selenium.WebElement>)'

Comment: Sorry, forgot to create UtilsClass instance )). I don't know how exactly calls your class, where explicitWait(). You have to create an instance of this classs and then use it's methods in another class. Please have a look in updated answer.

Comment: That was totally correct, I wasn't calling the utils class and hence throwing the error. I have called and fixed it now. Thank you for pointing out. It is working I am able to wait until the element is clickable.